# TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources. (Error in Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run [SparkPi](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala) example on my standalone mode cluster.

```
package org.apache.spark.examples
import scala.math.random
import org.apache.spark._

/** Computes an approximation to pi */
object SparkPi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkPi")
      .setMaster("spark://192.168.17.129:7077")
      .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val n = math.min(100000L * slices, Int.MaxValue).toInt // avoid overflow
    val count = spark.parallelize(1 until n, slices).map { i =>
    val x = random * 2 - 1
    val y = random * 2 - 1
    if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
    }.reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
    spark.stop()
    }
}
```

**Note:** I made a little change in this line:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkPi")
  .setMaster("spark://192.168.17.129:7077")
  .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
```

**Problem:** I'm using spark-shell (Scala interface) to run this code. When I try this code, I receive this error repeatedly:

```
15/02/09 06:39:23 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

**Note:** I can see my workers in my Master's WebUI and also I can see a new job in the **Running Applications** section. But there is no end for this application and I see error repeatedly.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot run this code inside the spark shell. What is the exact code you enter into the spark shell?

Comment: I simply copy and past this code into spark-shell and then call SparkPi.main(Array("10"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run this from spark shell, then start the shell with argument --master spark://192.168.17.129:7077 and enter the following code:

```
import scala.math.random
import org.apache.spark._
val slices = 10
val n = math.min(100000L * slices, Int.MaxValue).toInt // avoid overflow
val count = sc.parallelize(1 until n, slices).map { i =>
    val x = random * 2 - 1
    val y = random * 2 - 1
    if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _)
println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
```

Otherwise, compile the code into a jar and run it with spark-submit. But remove setMaster from the code and add it as 'master' argument to spark-submit script. Also remove the allowMultipleContexts argument from the code.

You need only one spark context.